# Having trouble when using Newtonsoft.Json.dll externally. Entry points can not be found

Tags: json.net, dllimport

A cad program called NX has to run a VB code in a specific project. Therefore I can not utilize nuget to install any library. I should call a dll and its methods inside the code.

```
Declare Auto Function GenerateJsonText Lib "D:\Lib\Nevtonsoft.Json.dll" Alias "SerializeObject" (ByVal inputObject As Object) As String
```

in order to call this:

```
Dim serializedText As String = GenerateJsonText(p)
```

here "p" is an object that is not detailed here.

When I run this cod I am getting an error :.... SerializeObject entry point has not been found in Newtonsoft.Json.dll

here you can find the namespace:
[namespace definitions](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm)